# Windows Azure Notification hub registration on iOS improperly formats tags

Tags: ios, swift, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm having trouble registering my (Swift) iOS application with the Azure Notification Hub, using tags.

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223265.aspx the request body to the notification hub should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <content type="application/xml">
        <AppleRegistrationDescription xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect">
            <Tags>myTag, myOtherTag</Tags>
            <DeviceToken>{DeviceToken}</DeviceToken> 
        </AppleRegistrationDescription>
    </content>
</entry>
```

However, when registering using the Azure SDK for iOs the <Tags> element looks like this:

```
<Tags>(myTag, myOtherTag)</Tags>
```

My code is as follows:

```
var tableArray = [String]()
.
.
.
let hub = SBNotificationHub(connectionString:delegate.notficationEndpoint, notificationHubPath:delegate.notficationHubPath)
let tags = NSSet(array:self.tableArray)   

// Register the new tags with the push server
hub.registerNativeWithDeviceToken(deviceToken, tags:tags)
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but i think this works:

```
let tags: [String] = ["myTag","myOtherTag"]
```

or in your case:

```
let tags: [String] = tableArray
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding on top of LoVo's Answer: on top of it.. we need to parse the tags as NSSet not NSArray so we need to convert it to  `Set<NSObject>`

```
let tags = ["myTag","myOtherTag"]
let tagSet = NSSet(array: tags) as  Set<NSObject>
```